# Decorator pattern to create a type

Tags: c#, decorator, single-responsibility-principle

Can the decorator pattern be used to create / build a type?

For example, lets say we want to hydrate an object. Arguably we can have a builder class that does it all but what if its a complex object with multiple layers, is it valid to have multiple decorators that hydrate a portion of that object and return it back to the caller?

For instance:

1. For instance we have `FirstDecorator` which calls an API and the result we instantiate the type and hydrate parts of it. Because this was a successful call, we will invoke the next decorator.
2. `SecondDecorator` then invokes an API but hydrates another aspect of the object.

I like this approach because I can have multiple decorators that hydrate a specific portion of the object and easily be extended by simply adding another decorator to the sequence.

The problem here is with definition and is this leaning towards Chain of Responsibility (CoR)? My understanding is that CoR allows you to terminate the chain at anytime and not allow the other processors to act. Decorator pattern implies that all must be executed? The difference between the two is very sketchy to me.

> The chain-of-responsibility pattern is structurally nearly identical
> to the decorator pattern, the difference being that for the decorator,
> all classes handle the request, while for the chain of responsibility,
> exactly one of the classes in the chain handles the request. This is a
> strict definition of the Responsibility concept in the GoF book.
> However, many implementations (such as loggers below, or UI event
> handling, or servlet filters in Java, etc) allow several elements in
> the chain to take responsibility.

The code example I have:

```
public interface IPokemonDecorator
{
    // Every decorator will hydrate a part of PokeApiResponse
    Task Decorate(PokeApiResponse pokeApiResponse, PokeRequest request);
}

public class BasicInfoDecorator
{
    private readonly IPokemonDecorator _pokemonDecorator;
    private readonly IPokemonApiAdapter _pokemonApiAdapter;

    public BasicInfoDecorator(
        IPokemonDecorator pokemonDecorator,
        IPokemonApiAdapter pokemonApiAdapter)
    {
        _pokemonDecorator = pokemonDecorator;
        _pokemonApiAdapter = pokemonApiAdapter;
    }
    
    public async Task Decorate(PokeApiResponse pokeApiResponse, PokeRequest request)
    {
        var httpResponse = await _pokemonApiAdapter.Execute($"api/v2/pokemon/{request.Name}", request);
        pokeApiResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<PokeApiResponse>();

        if (pokeApiResponse != null)
        {
            request.Id = pokeApiResponse.Id.ToString();
            await _pokemonDecorator.Decorate(pokeApiResponse, request);
        }
    }
}

public class DetailedInfoDecorator
{
    private readonly PokeApiAdapter _pokemonApiAdapter;

    public DetailedInfoDecorator(PokeApiAdapter pokemonApiAdapter)
    {
        _pokemonApiAdapter = pokemonApiAdapter;
    }
    
    public async Task Decorate(PokeApiResponse pokeApiResponse, PokeRequest request)
    {
        var httpResponse = await _pokemonApiAdapter.Execute($"api/v2/pokemon-species/{request.Id}", request);
        var details = await httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<SpeciesDetails>();
        pokeApiResponse.SpeciesDetails = GetDescriptionOrDefault(request, details);
    }

    private static SpeciesDetails GetDescriptionOrDefault(PokeRequest request, SpeciesDetails speciesDetails)
    {
        // some logic to get description based on default language or requested language
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Arguably can do the same using an application service that orchestrates the calls and gets the responses and then passes it to a builder to construct the object.

Is this a violation of the principle?

Comment: I guess for your use case strategy pattern will work. based on the strategy you will plug those functionality. This is what we do in api right? for one api flavor you will add one strategy for other you will use another strategy.

Comment: I guess I can have multiple levels of this whereas a strategy doesn't allow this to happen so easily from my understanding? I guess I am trying to do something like the asp.net middleware which is based on the decorator pattern where you can endlessly add functionality.

Comment: Middleware implements the chain of responsibility principle. This you can implement to customize the endless requirement.

Comment: I believe the CoR is perhaps what I am doing above as the key difference being I can short-circuit and not call the next invocation. The decorator implies all decorators must be called..

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to create new types at runtime. What is the class used for? Does it just contain data that's returned from an API? Are there methods they implement differently? Is there a common interface that they all implement?

Comment: The only things these decorators do is call an API and hydrate as aspect of the object. It will also contain some minor logic like filtering descriptions based on language passed in. @Scott Hannen read your blog about mediatr, loved it btw great work

Comment: But in a nutshell the signature is the same as the object is modified by reference. I'll update the question to show this with a simpler example.